# regex to match string not containg at least X characters

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex to match a string that doesn't contain at least three characters [a-zA-Z]

```
Valid Strings: 
abc12345
asd
abc12321!!

Invalid Strings:
aa!
111!!!a
!!!!!!b
```

Comment: Also, do you want a string of three consecutive characters or should there just be at least three characters at random locations in the string?

Comment: @wared I would think the OP cares about the regular expression in general, not a particular implementation in a certain language or library.

Comment: I ended up using ^(?:[^\p{L}]*[\p{L}]){0,2}[^\p{L}]*$ to support also the non-unicode characters. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use:

```
(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3,}[^a-zA-Z]*
```

You can find an explaination of this regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/jB8gZ8).

matches:

```
abc12345
asd
abc12321!!
a85ug
83nj%@8n2
```

doesn't match:

```
aa!
111!!!a
!!!!!!b
a59&*@g9
```

Comment: The last part `[^a-zA-Z]*` is not mandatory. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: @M42 I know, but without it the regex may not match the entire string.

Comment: It's not a problem because at least 3 alphabetic chars is reach with or without the last part.

Comment: `(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3,}` only matches the `a$yg` part of `a$yg623`. I think acidrat wants it to match the _entire_ string.

Comment: @RyanCarlson and how do i reverse it? i want to get a match if the string doesnt comply to the rule

Comment: @acidrat `^(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){0,2}[^a-zA-Z]*$` should work. Explanation: http://regex101.com/r/oT0aR1

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the following regex matches the string:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3,}
```

If it doesn't match then the string is invalid.

Basically the `{3,}` part of the regex says the the previous character class should be matched at least three times. It's pretty flexible in that you can specify a minimum number and a maximum number of times required for a match like so: `{MIN,MAX}` and if you omit either MIN or MAX then only the value specified is used (i.e. `{3,}` means *at least* 3, whereas `{,3}` would mean *at most* 3)